# .htaccess - Redirect all the pages after domain name to another url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to move the user from this url :

```
http://example.com/USERNAME
```

I want to redirect this address to this url:

```
http://example.com/index.php?p=admins&user=USERNAME
```

I've this code in my htaccess but it's not working :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)$
RewriteRule /(.*)$ index.php?p=admins&user==$1 [L]
```

how can I do  it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following. Kindly make sure to clear your browser cache before testing URLs in your browser. You need to place a condition to stop continuous looping hence I have put a condition to check if a query string is NULL then only proceed for rewriting further.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=admins&user=$1 [L]
```